# CSS: Create border around multiple objects

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a css border around multiple objects with different sizes.
The picture below shows what i want to accomplish: (blue square = span, green square = div, gray border is what I want)

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcCsK.png)

What I've tried so far is drawing only top, left and right border for the span element and then draw the whole border for the div. Then let them overlap with negative margin.

However this is not a very good solution as it doesn't always match up in different zoom stages..

Is there any better method to do this?

Comment: Can you provide the code that doesn't work nicely with zoom factors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a table and fancy bordering.

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="header"><span>Test</span></td>
    <td class="space"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="content" colspan="2">
      Test content
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
  width:1%;
  white-space:nowrap;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.space {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.content {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ao4hbt2q/11/ should be self explanatory. Just have to make sure you set cellspacing to 0 for the table and set the "span" cell to the width of the content.

Edit: if you're reading this you're probably a person averse to creating tables. Tables are a very under-used and great part of HTML. They seem "dated" in an era of bootstrap and fancy frameworks, but they're often the best solution to a positioning problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify with CSS which edges of a container receive a border. So for your example you could try something like this:

```
span { 
border-top:    5px solid grey;
border-right:  5px solid grey; 
border-left:   5px solid grey;
}

div { 
border-right:  5px solid grey; 
border-bottom: 5px solid grey;
border-left:   5px solid grey;
}
```

This could be shortened to something like this:

```
span {
border:        5px solid grey
border-bottom: 0
}
div {
border:        5px solid grey
border-top:    0
}
```